# I used pack_padded_sequence() and put in lstm layer, but I got start () + length () exceeds dimension size (). error

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, pytorch

In my model, there are a embedding layer, a conv1d layer, a lstm layer. And I'm using Pytorch.
My question is: 
When I put `pack = pack_padded_sequence(conv)` in the lstm layer, I got `RuntimeError: start (pack[0].size(0)) + length (1) exceeds dimension size (pack[0].size(0)).` error. Why I got this error? And What does mean?? Please help me..

```py
class CNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size: int, embed_size: int, out_size: int, filter_size: List[int], hidden_size: int,
                 layer_num: int, pad: int = 1):
        super().__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.pad = pad
        self.out_size = out_size
        self.filter_size = filter_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.layer_num = layer_num

        self.embed = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings=self.vocab_size,
            embedding_dim=self.embed_size,
            padding_idx=self.pad,
        )

        self.cnn = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=self.embed_size,
            out_channels=self.out_size,
            kernel_size=self.filter_size[0],
            bias=True,
        )

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(
            input_size=self.out_size,
            hidden_size=self.hidden_size,
            num_layers=self.layer_num,
            bidirectional=True,
            batch_first=True,
        )

    def forward(self, batch):
        embed = self.embed(batch.word[0])  # [B(64), L(465), F(256)]
        embed = embed.transpose(1, 2)  # [B(64), L(256), F(465)]

        conv = self.cnn(embed)  # [B(64), F(64), L(465)]
        conv = conv.transpose(1, 2)  # [B(64), L(465), F(64)]

        encoding = pack_padded_sequence(conv,
                                        [tensor.item() for tensor in batch.word[1]],
                                        batch_first=True)
        print(f'encoding => {encoding[0].size()}')  # [8093, 64]
                print(f'encoding => {encoding[1].size()}')  # [465]
        _, (h, _) = self.lstm(encoding)  # [bsz, sln, dim3]
        print(f'h => {h}')
```

And result like below.

```
 File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 182, in forward
    self.num_layers, self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional)
RuntimeError: start (8093) + length (1) exceeds dimension size (8093).
```

Comment: This might be an off by one error. Try to modify the end by one